# CodeLens shows incoming changes from branches / folders deleted from TFS

Tags: branch, azure-devops, codelens

We had deleted some old unused branches and now CodeLens shows incoming changes from those deleted branches above every single method in our solution.

[incoming changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx67n.png)

We've tried to convert branch to folder and then delete it but with no luck.
Also I tried solution from this topic https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/812e6977-7064-474b-b0e1-7f3ab6c53bfc/ , but still - no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since the question is for Azure DevOps Services, I'll leave the on premise steps in a comment instead of an answer. First, run `TfsConfig codeIndex /collectionName:<collectionName> /ignoreList:add $/<project>/<branch>*`, then `TfsConfig codeIndex /collectionName:<collectionName> /rebuildAll`. Then restart Visual Studio and reopen your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CodeIndex command in TFSConfig to delete or rebuild the CodeLens data https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#codeindex

Comment: Is there any way to run it on visualstudio.com?

Comment: Don't believe so. Might want to change the tags on you question if you're using the hosted versions.

Comment: This also happens with self installed TFS, what a disaster. Every branch we delete is showing up as an incoming change that the entire file is going to be removed. In order to fix this you have to completely "destroy" the branch after deleting it. I don't like to do that in order to keep a history for a period of time.